# Upgrade from Drupal 6 to 7

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-7

I try to upgrade 6 to 7.

> 7061 - Migrate upload.module data to the newly created file field.
>   7062 - Replace 'system_list' index with 'bootstrap' index on {system}.
>   7063 - Delete {menu_links} records for 'type' => MENU_CALLBACK which
>   would not appear in a fresh install.
>   7064 - Remove block_callback field from {menu_router}. 7065 - Remove the default value
>   for sid.
>   7066 - Migrate the 'file_directory_temp' variable.
>   7067 - Grant
>   administrators permission to view the administration theme.
>   7068 - Update {url_alias}.language description.
>   7069 - Remove the obsolete 'site_offline' variable. @see update_fix_d7_requirements()

for the first I have an error so nothing update..

this is the error

Answer (score 3):

If the original update procedure stopped at update 7061, that's where the error is. You'll probably need to roll your database all the way back to the 6.x version and try again.

Might be related to [#966210: DB Case Sensitivity: system_update_7061() fails on inserting files with same name but different case.](http://drupal.org/node/966210)